# siwfty json parsing fails

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

i m making an ios app...i am using alamofire and swiftyjson for api calls. but swiftyjson is failing to parse the following json response...

```
{"meta":{"status":200},"response":"You will be notified when we will be in your region"}
```

my code:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, newsletterRegistraionUrl, parameters: params)
            .responseString { response in

                indicator.stopAnimating();
                switch(response.result){
                case .Success:
                    if let r = response.result.value {
                        var jsonResponse = JSON(r);

                        print(jsonResponse.stringValue)
                        if jsonResponse[META][STATUS].isExists() {
                            if jsonResponse[META][STATUS].intValue == apiSuccess {
                                if let message = jsonResponse[RESPONSE].string {
                                    self.makeAlert(message);
                                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(NEWSLETTERSUCCESSIDENTIFIRE, sender: self);
                                }
                            }else {
                                self.makeAlert(APIERROR);
                            }
                            print(jsonResponse[META][STATUS].intValue)
                            print("sss")
                        }
//                        

                    }
                    break;
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error.description);
                    self.makeAlert(APIERROR);
                    break;
                }



        }
```

the value of status i m getting after parsing is 0. not sure where i am messing...

Answer (score 0):

Can you check NSAppTransportSecurity info .Plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
```

add this and try it